# How to force mouseover event to fire before mouseout event completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, onmouseover, mouseout

I am using jquery to make a simple dropdown effect. The dropdown box will appear instantly when the user hovers over the trigger element, and fade out when the mouse leaves the trigger element.

```
$('ul > li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('#dropDown').show();
},function(){
    $(this).find('#dropDown').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

The problem, as you will see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7x8ux39/4/) is that the mouseover event (dropdown box appears) will not fire if the mouseout event (dropdown box fades out) has not yet completed. Does anyone know if there is a way to force the dropdown box to appear regardless of whether the fade has completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `.finish()` to finish the previous animation:

```
$('ul > li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('#dropDown').finish().show();
},function(){
    $(this).find('#dropDown').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h85a4e92/).

Comment: Perfect! will accept answer in 9 minutes as allowed!